# How to align two datasets for cross validation in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot, cross-validation

I have two data sets about coordinates of the same movement saved by two different tracking systems. As can be seen from the two plots, they are similar however they are not aligned because of different frame rate and processing speed.
Is there a way in MATLAB to align or resample those two data sets for cross validation?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into Dynamic Time Warping, as a way of aligning two similar sequences that are out of phase and/or different frequencies:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/43156-dynamic-time-warping--dtw-

Here's the Wikeipedia article on it:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping